# SonarQube complaining to Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true"

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-analysis

I am facing this issue in line number 2 while resolving sonarqube issue please suggest alternative to resolve it.

```
Exception exe = Server.GetLastError();
  if (exe != null) {
   Exception errorInfo = exe.GetBaseException();
   var error = errorInfo as HttpException;
   if (error != null)
    isNotFound = error.GetHttpCode() == (int) System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share the signatures of all methods, and types of all objects, in short, make a [mcve]? It would help tremendously to know *which* `Server` object you're talking to.

Comment: does `Server.GetLastError();` return null if there are no errors?

Comment: i am getting issue for IF condition it is violating sonarqube rule: **csharpsquid:S2583**. Please refer url it will be more helpful : [http://tinypic.com/r/rtqeld/9](http://tinypic.com/r/rtqeld/9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you attached in your comment helped a lot.

There is a line that contains `NLogManager.Error(... + exe.StackTrace);` if it is executed correctly, then `exe` is not `null`, hence the `if` statement is redundant.

The analyzer does not raise issue on `exe.StackTrace` because at this point it is not sure if `exe` could be null or not (there is no check before).

I would recommend moving the line with `NLogManager` inside the `if` statement.